# flutter and stripe (setupIntents)

Tags: django, flutter, stripe-payments

I know this library [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe), which to me seems to be very limited in stripe interactions, it only does paymentIntent creation and that is basically it. Please do argue if I am wrong.

I am looking forward to see if there are other packages, if any, for flutter to interact with stripe in more depth, I am trying to avoid Android/IOS native languages.

I do these in backend: create stripe customer, create setup intent for each customer as they try or either add bank card or make purchase.

I am looking forward that client will interact to stripe for the following: 
1 Confirm setup intents 
2 Send card data to stripe

Another question, could you please assess my payment flow? If it is faulty please recommend another way 
Once setupintent is confirmed for the user, they hit backend for whatever purchase they want to make, backend contacts Stripe, fetches the setupintent, creates and confirms the paymentintent.

Thank you, I appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payment flow looks normal and it's basically outlined in [Stripe SetupIntent Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse). The Doc only has Web/ iOS/ Android/ React Native, but the flow should be the same.

There is also [an example inside flutter-stripe's repo](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/others/setup_future_payment_screen.dart) for SetupIntent. Both resources should be enough well-explained reference for adapting to your implementation.